# Blueimp File Upload and Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, blueimp

When I create a non-CI directory called utils and put the server/php code in it and call it from a CI controller, everything works fine. I dynamically alter the upload directory and that works as well. The json that is returned on completion is as follows:

```
{
    "files": [{
        "name": "pob1.pptx",
        "size": 2234155,
        "type": "application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.myurl.com\/media\/ppt\/1\/pob1.pptx",
        "delete_url": "https:\/\/www.myurl.com\/media\/ppt\/1\/?file=pob1.pptx",
        "delete_type": "DELETE"
    }]
}
```

---

When I copy the UploadHandler.php to the libraries folder and use a controller to launch the file upload, it also works and I get the file uploaded to my custom directory as expected. But what is weird is the system is returning a second json file appended to the first and it is throwing an "invalid character after end of json file" error. Json file is below:

```
{
    "files": [{
        "name": "pob1.pptx",
        "size": 2234155,
        "type": "application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.myurl.com\/media\/ppt\/1\/pob1.pptx",
        "delete_url": "https:\/\/www.myurl.com\/media\/ppt\/1\/?file=pob1.pptx",
        "delete_type": "DELETE"
    }]
} {
    "files": [{
        "name": "pob1 (1).pptx",
        "size": 0,
        "type": "application\/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
        "error": "abort",
        "delete_url": "https:\/\/www.myurl.com\/media\/ppt\/1\/?file=pob1%20%281%29.pptx",
        "delete_type": "DELETE"
    }]
}
```

Note that these two are identical in the first part. The second block of json starting with a 'files' attribute gets added in the CI example. And note that this instance has the updated upload filename as though it were trying to upload it twice. What could be causing this? Something in the CI implementation?

Any ideas? This is VERY close to being an awesome Codeigniter solution.

This is all new Blueimp 6.1 with jQuery 1.8.3 and jquery-ui 1.9.2, although I don't think that matters except for UI considerations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was calling the submit method and NOT turning off the initialize feature. My bad. Problem solved.